# How can I make my confluence documentation readable on mobile devices

Tags: android, wiki, confluence

I have been using Atlassian Confluence for some time as a documentation tool.
I recently tried looking at the documentation using the inbuilt Chrome browser on a 7" tablet.

To my surprise I found that the left hand navigation tree/menu was completely absent meaning that users cannot navigate past the first page.

I cannot find any way around this and I am hoping for suggestions as to how to make the documentation usable on mobile devices.

Comment: You might want to start with a quick check to see if your OS is supported: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Supported+Platforms

Comment: Here's a breakdown of how confluence should work on mobile: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Confluence+on+a+Mobile+Device it's worth noting what version of confluence you're running. It might be time to upgrade in order to get a better mobile experience

Comment: I have already looked at all the confluence pages that I can find. I am running 3.5. However when looking at Atlassian's own pages that are running version 5+ I still get a different veiw on the tablet and cannot see the navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the side navigation bar to display is to tap on the dropdown menu on the top right side of the Chrome browser and select 'Request Desktop Site'.

This is not really very satisfactory for users trying to read the documentation however as they will not even be aware that a left hand navigation menu exists and still less likely to know how to request the desktop site.

Not really a very satisfactory answer but thought I would put what I had found here in case it is useful for somebody.